# What is the most efficient way of turning this list into a string?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, nested-lists

I'm trying to create a string consisting of elements from a dictionary value.

```
For line in dictionary:
    print 'Category'.format(line['categories'])
```

This is the result of running the code above:

```
Category = [[u'Cafes', u'cafes'], [u'Pakistani', u'pakistani'], [u'Halal', u'halal']]
Category = [u'American (New)', u'newamerican'], [u'Desserts', u'desserts']]
```

When I use this:

```
for x in line['categories']:
    cat =', '.join(x)
    print cat
```

This is the result:

```
Cafes, cafes
Pakistani, pakistani
Halal, halal

American (New), newamerican
Desserts , desserts
```

What I'm trying to achieve is :

```
'Cafes, cafes, Pakistani, pakistani, Halal, halal'
American (New), newamerican, Desserts , desserts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
ss = ''
for x in line['categories']:
    cat =', '.join(x)
    ss += cat

print ss
```